# How to pivot values in column and aggregate count in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pivot

I have following PySpark dataframe:

| Type | SubType |
| --- | --- |
| Type1 | SubType 1 |
| Type1 | SubType 1 |
| Type1 | SubType 1 |
| Type1 | SubType 2 |
| Type1 | SubType 3 |
| Type2 | SubType 1 |
| Type2 | SubType 1 |
| Type2 | SubType 2 |
| Type2 | SubType 2 |
| Type2 | SubType 2 |
| Type2 | SubType 3 |
| Type2 | SubType 3 |
| Type3 | SubType 1 |
| Type3 | SubType 1 |

My requirement is to pivot based on `SubType` and aggregate for the count of `SubType`s for each type. My expected output is:

| Type | SubType 1 | SubType 2 | SubType 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| Type 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| Type 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried using the pivot function but somehow the aggregation is not happening:

```
df = df \
    .groupby(df.Type) \
    .pivot("SubType") \
    .agg(
       F.count('SubType')
    )
```

Will someone please help me to get a solution here?

Comment: what did not work in your attempt? it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code here (changed from pandas to pyspark)
Can you check if it works for you?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import count


# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create the DataFrame
data = [
    ('Type1', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type1', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type1', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type1', 'SubType2'),
    ('Type1', 'SubType3'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType2'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType2'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType2'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType3'),
    ('Type2', 'SubType3'),
    ('Type3', 'SubType1'),
    ('Type3', 'SubType1')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['Type', 'SubType'])

# Pivot the DataFrame and aggregate by count
pivot_df = df.groupBy('Type').pivot('SubType').agg(count('SubType').alias('count'))

# Fill any missing values with 0
pivot_df = pivot_df.fillna(0)

# Display the result
pivot_df.show()
```

I tested it also. Here are the results:

```
$ python app.py                                                                                                                                                

Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/05/27 12:31:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| Type|SubType1|SubType2|SubType3|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|Type2|       2|       3|       2|
|Type3|       2|       0|       0|
|Type1|       3|       1|       1|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I've inserted table but somehow it is not getting properly formatted in the question. But, what you've considered is exactly correct and that's what I need. I tried using it already but I'm getting following error
'A DataFrame object does not have an attribute pivot_table. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.'
bdw Im doing it in pySpark and not python

Comment: Hello, You did it in python, I'm using pyspark. I need solution in pySpark and not python.

Comment: I suppose you mean pyspark instead of pandas. Sorry my bad. Will fix the answer in a minute

Comment: I fixed it. Above is the python code. You can execute either with python or pyspark shell.